# Como recuperar apenas 1 valor da URL com CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou passando dois parâmetros
http://localhost/topsamp-ci/votar/4-slug-de-algo

```
 public function votar($id) {
    echo $id;
    die;
 }
```

E ele me retorna 4-slug-de-algo. Eu queria apenas recuperar o ID mas exibindo na url os dois parametros, como eu faço isso?

Minha rota está assim:

```
$route['votar/(:any)'] = 'Home/votar/$1';
```

Botão de votar

```
<a href="<?= base_url("votar/{$row->id}-{$row->slug}"); ?>" class="btn btn-vote">VOTAR</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delimitação do parâmetro é a barra `/`

Precisa montar o link assim:

```
<a href="<?= base_url("votar/{$row->id}/{$row->slug}"); ?>" class="btn btn-vote">VOTAR</a>
```

Troque o traço `-` pela barra `/`

Fica assim:  http://localhost/topsamp-ci/votar/4/slug-de-algo

Se quiser manter do outro jeito, irá receber tudo junto mesmo, ai tem fatiar a string.

Comment: Funcionou cara, vou deixar assim mesmo por segurança obrigado!

Comment: Eu já ia fazer isso, porém estava dando erro tinha que esperar 7 minutos haha, vlw!